# Knex & postgres connection error - error: role "admin" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, knex.js

I am trying to connect to postgres db image using knex. But I am getting error:-
 `error: role "admin" does not exist`

My knexfile is ass below:

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    debug: true,
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    },

    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname + '/src/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: __dirname + '/src/seeds'
    }
  }
};
```

And my docker-compose file is:-

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESS_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRESS_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  pgadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/pgadmin-data:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Environment variables are straight forward

```
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
POSTGRES_DB=configs
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
```

Packages details:

```
  "knex": "^0.21.1",
  "pg": "^8.3.0"
```

I ran command `docker-compose up` and on completion i created migrations and post that i ran `npx knex migrate:latest`. This is resulting in error

```
error: role "admin" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/test/packages/config-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
```

I am not able to debug and fix. Please help.

Comment: Do you have an ```admin``` role in the database? Generally the superuser for Postgres is ```postgres```. Also the ```env``` variable names are wrong if you are trying to use these  [env](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) Also they are spelled differently in your compose file versus what you show later.